# Best way to migrate ETL-Jobs from free Talend Open Studio to Talend Server?

Tags: talend

I have lot of defined etl jobs in talend open studio. This etl-jobs are in dedicate git repo (whole workspace). But now we want move this etl jobs to talend server. And whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

create a new online project on the server then import your whole local project. It has to be the same version or newer to be able to do that.